# Getting error while trying to delete a model object in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite, django-views

```py
def employee_delete(request, id=None):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    #user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(type(user))
        self.user.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('employee_list'))
    else:
        context = {}
        context['user'] = user
        return render(request, 'employee/delete.html', context)
```

**Error showing while deleting the object using delete() in django 2.1.5**

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Instead of pasting a screenshot of part of the error page, click the link on that page that says "Switch to copy-and-paste view" and paste the error text here.

Comment: Show your model. I think there is something wrong in there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman
File "F:\Pycharm\ems\ems\employee\views.py" in employee_delete
  59.   
File "F:\Pycharm\ems\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in delete
  879.         collector.collect([self], keep_parents=keep_parents)

File "F:\Pycharm\ems\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py" in collect
  221.                         field.remote_field.on_delete(self, field, sub_objs, self.using)

Exception Type: TypeError at /employee/4/delete/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable      user.delete()

Comment: I am using the inbuilt User Model of django

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi

Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete="CASCADE")
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    salary = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-salary',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}{1}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.profile.save()

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Don't post code in comments; edit your question and post the traceback and models there, properly formatted.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi

The change that you told me to make in the models.py files worked correctly.
Thank you very much......It was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

You are creating function based view. So don't use `self`

```
def employee_delete(request, id=None):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    #user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(type(user))
        user.delete() # change here
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('employee_list'))
    else:
        context = {}
        context['user'] = user
        return render(request, 'employee/delete.html', context)
```

Updates

In your `models.py` you are using string CASCADE

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # update like this
```

Comment: This is true, but not the cause of the error OP is having.